# How to properly deal with Celery and Azure Storage queues containing a '/' character in the access key?

Tags: python, celery, urlencode, azure-storage-queues

I am creating a Celery application using the syntax

```
celery_app = Celery(
    my_config_name,
    backend=my_backend,
    broker=my_broker,
)
```

For `my_broker`, I am using the address of an Azure storage account that reads

```
my_broker = "azurestoragequeues://:jrIEoHgyi7y8L7dJ+0CeYGnR9rHLwzMRsKzrmUle7ZL8OA/EaO5aBxqEYSB2VPXJ2v4C58D==@myazurequeue"
```

and note that the password bit contains a '/' (that's the corresponding access key that can be read also in the Azure portal).

If I run my code, I get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jrIEoHgyi7y8L7dJ+0CeYGnR9rHLwzMRsKzrmUle7ZL8OA'
```

which is the same error that I get with

```
from kombu.utils.url import parse_url
parse_url(my_broker)
```

One fix that seems to work is something along the lines of

```
from kombu.utils.url import safequote
my_broker_fixed = "azurestoragequeues://:" + safequote(str.replace(my_broker, "azurestoragequeues://:", ""), safe = "=@")
```

which can encode the '/' character in the access key only (but not in the rest of the address).
This also parses fine when firing `parse_url(my_broker)` as it yields

```
{'hostname': 'myazurequeue',
 'password': 'jrIEoHgyi7y8L7dJ+0CeYGnR9rHLwzMRsKzrmUle7ZL8OA/EaO5aBxqEYSB2VPXJ2v4C58D==',
 'port': None,
 'transport': 'azurestoragequeues',
 'userid': None,
 'virtual_host': None}
```

This seems to be OK as a workaround, but is there a better fix?

Comment: Aw, looking better on GitHub I see this very related issue: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5532 , still maybe someone has a better solution?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417851/django-celery-4-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-when-start?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The password is the part of the Transport connection that needs to be safely quoted.

Store the username, password, hostname for the connection as environment variables and read those in your application.

```py
from kombu.utils.url import safequote

TRANSPORT_USER = os.getenv('TRANSPORT_USER'),
TRANSPORT_PASS = safequote(os.getenv('TRANSPORT_PASS')),
TRANSPORT_HOST = os.getenv('TRANSPORT_HOST')

my_broker = f'azurestoragequeues://{TRANSPORT_USER}:{TRANSPORT_PASS}@{TRANSPORT_HOST}'
```

Comment: Could you expand on this and spell out what the TRANSPORT_USER, TRANSPORT_PASS, and TRANSPORT_HOST should be in this case?